# Spring MVC 3 RequestMapping with regular expresssion quantifiers

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

The method below fails with 
"PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed counted closure near index ... "

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/{id:[0-9|a-z]{15}}")
public View view(@PathVariable final String id) {
  ...
}
```

Looks like the pattern matcher is trimming too much off the the string and losing the last }.

Does anyone know a work around to this bug? I'm having to drop the qualifier to "/{id:[0-9|a-z]+}" - which frankly suck!

Comment: @mdrg It's the qualifier that breaks, not the expression itself. I suppose the or is not really needed.

Comment: tried : (value ="/{id:[0-9|a-z]{15, }}") ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are any good workarounds for this case except for manual validation. After all, `{name:regexp}` syntax was introduced for solving ambiguities between mappings rather than for validation.

`@Valid` on `@PathVariable`s could be a solution, but it's promised only in Spring 3.1 ([SPR-6380](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6380)).

Also feel free to report this bug in [Spring JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa), although I don't expect them to fix it quickly since path variable handling code is already a mess.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution. It's butt-ugly, but it's equivalent to what you'd like to have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]" +
        "[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]" +
        "[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]}") // 15 repetitions of [0-9a-z]
```

If that's the only way to get what you need, you might as well use this monster.

Comment: wow !  shame in would have to be 32 times. 15 was just a random number for the post. Now I have to debate if this is actually the "right" answer.

Comment: I could pull it out into a static final string with a reasonable name. I'll give you an up vote for sheer cleverness. :)

Comment: @dom sometimes an evil hack is the only way to go :-)

Comment: Well, for that there is the "x times" expression in regexps [0-9a-z]{15} or if there is no ambiguity with another controller just [0-9a-z]* and then in the controller validate the digitcount and provide a nice error message